# MS SQL Concatenate multiple values into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I currently have the following table;

```
Invoice   Client   Purchase Order
1000      A1       1234
1000      A1       1235
1001      B2       1236
1001      B2       1237
1002      B2       1238
```

and I'm looking for a quick way to get to;

```
Invoice   Client   Purchase Orders
1000      A1       1234 1235
1001      B2       1236 1237
1002      B2       1238
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Tag the DBMS you are using. The answer to this is depends on it.

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: I hope you are not planning on saving the grouped values in a column, right?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking, because without knowing your database, we can't help you.  But, your question is probably a duplicate of several others anyway.

Comment: Asked and answered a thousand times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-aggregation+sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your given details, assuming a table `#temp` below, with sample data:

```
create table #temp (
     invoice int,
     client varchar(5),
    [purchase order]  int
)

insert into #temp
select 1000,'A1',1234  union all
select 1000,'A1',1235  union all
select 1001,'B2',1236  union all
select 1001,'B2',1237  union all
select 1002,'B2',1238
```

Now you can use below query using [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-path-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-2017) as per your required output:

```
select distinct tp1.invoice,tp1.client,  
(  
    SELECT convert(varchar(10),[purchase order]) + ' ' as [text()]  
    from #temp tp  
    where tp.invoice=tp1.invoice and tp.client=tp1.client  
    for XML path('')  
) as [purchase order]  
from #temp tp1
```

If you have any query, let me know.